# Getting 401, 403 over a simple API call with AngularJS on a localhost

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, spotify-app

I have an account on Napster developers. And, I made an app, and I got an api key. [According to Napster documents](https://developer.napster.com/api/v2.2#getting-started) Here is what I send as a GET request over UPC.

```
function getByUpc() {
    console.log("getByUpc is called ...");
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.napster.com/v2.2/albums/upc/602498619070',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'BASIC my-apikey'
        }
    }).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by id'))
}
```

I changed BASIC to Bearer, but I also get a same result (401 error).
Also, [I tried to put apikey as a query string](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/napsterapi/zgxkPvV5pk4) but I get 403 error.
Any suggestion?

```
http://api.napster.com/v2.2/albums/upc/602498619070?apikey=MY-APIKEY
```

Comment: The documentation shows a header with the name `apikey`; your code uses a header with the name `Authorization`. Why does the code not follow the documentation?

Comment: @georgeawg, this seems to be the correct answer. Why don't you post it as an answer, not comment?

Comment: @georgeawg  this answer receives 403 error